# Get Insert Statement for existing row in sqlite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have database **A** for caching and **B** at the server, so I want to send a row from **A** to **B** and for that I need to generate the insert statement for already existed row in **A**.

**below is what I want to accomplish**

```
get insert select * from table where myId = 5;
```

and **it should return**

```
insert into table(myId,Col1,Col2,...) VALUES (5,'value1','value2',...);
```

[I already had looked into this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978326/get-insert-statement-for-existing-row-in-mysql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166459/sql-server-how-to-generate-an-insert-statement-for-the-rows-in-an-existing-ta), that are not addressing my question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @duffymo what you are referring to is the copying of row from table1 to table2 on the same physical database, while mine is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

The `sqlite3` command-line shell can generate such an output, but without column names, for queries:

```sql
sqlite> .mode insert MyTableName
sqlite> SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 5;
INSERT INTO MyTableName VALUES(5,'value',NULL);
```

If you want the column names, you have to generate them manually:

```sql
SELECT 'INSERT INTO MyTable(a, b, c) VALUES (' ||
       quote(a) || ',' ||
       quote(b) || ',' ||
       quote(c) || ');'
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = 5;
--> INSERT INTO MyName(a, b, c) VALUES (42,'value',NULL);
```

(The same string operations could be done in Java.)

If your program does not know the exact database schema, you can read the list of columns for each table with [PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info), and construct the statement from that:

```sql
> create table MyTable(myId, Col1, Col2, [...]);
> pragma table_info(MyTable);
cid         name        type        notnull     dflt_value  pk        
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           myId                    0                       0         
1           Col1                    0                       0         
2           Col2                    0                       0         
3           ...                     0                       0
```

Comment: thank you for your response. but I cannot specify the columns as they are quite large in numbers for a table.
Seems like I cannot achieve for what I asked the question.